# dm function is not working on discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a DM command in a Discord Bot based on JavaScript but my code is throwing an error.

```js
function dm(message, args) {
    let dUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())
        || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

    if (!dUser) return message.channel.send(geengebruiker);

    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD'))
        return message.channel,send(geenstaff);

    let dMessage = args.join(' ').slice(22);
    if (dMessage.length < 1) return message.channel.send(geenbericht);
      
    dUser.send(`${dUser}`, staffdm, `${dMessage}`);
      
    message.author.send(
        `${message.author}`, senddm, `${dUser}`
    );
}
```

The error I get: https://prnt.sc/10rxzct

Answer (score 0):

By placing commas between your strings when you call [`TextChannel#Send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), it actually means that you're passing them as different parameters to the method. What you want to do is combine them into a single string and simply call it as `TextChannel.send("your string");`.

Examples:

```js
dUser.send(`${dUser} ${staffdm} ${dMessage}`);
```

```js
message.author.send(`${message.author} ${senddm} ${dUser}`);
```

You also have a syntax error:

```js
return message.channel,send(geenstaff);
```

should be

```
return message.channel.send(geenstaff);
```

Comment: can you help toe make it in a embed like this.

[link](https://prnt.sc/10wqbon)

Comment: @BryanRoyvonRotz If you ask another question, then I and many others can help you with that. Also, if this answer helped you, then please don't forget to accept it!